# Formal languages

Tags: computability, formal-languages

Let language $L$ be denoted by the regular expression $a^*b^*$

What is wrong with the following “proof” that $L$ is not regular?

Assume that $L$ is regular. Then it must be defined by a DFA with k states, for some integer $k > 0$. Take the string $w = (a)^k (b)^k$ and split it $w = xyz$, with $y = ab$. Then $(wy^2) z$ is not in $L$, which contradicts the pumping lemma. Therefore, $L$ cannot be regular.

Answer (score 2):

**Revised to match the intended question.**

You’re forgetting the statement of the pumping lemma: it says that you can split $a^kb^k$ as $xyz$ in such a way that $|xy|\le k$, $|y|\ge 1$, and $xy^iz\in L$ for each $i\ge 0$. The requirement that $|xy|\le k$ means that $xy$ consists entirely of $a$s. If $x=a^r$ and $y=a^s$, where $r+s\le k$ and $s\ge 1$, then $z=a^{k-r-s}b^k$, and for each $i\ge 0$ we have

$$xy^iz=a^ra^{is}a^{k-r-s}b^k=a^{is+k-s}b^k=a^{k+(i-1)s}b^k\;,$$

which *is* in $L$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help :)

Comment: @user142743, This doesn't answer your question correctly, as you intended it. Because of the way Math.SE formatted your question, the Kleene stars were omitted and Brian's answer is based on that botched version of your question.

Comment: @kviiri: Thanks: I didn’t look at the raw text. I improved your edit slightly to raise the Kleene stars.

Comment: Thanks - I was on my cellphone and forgot how those rendered.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the choice of $wyz$. Proving that a single possible partitioning doesn't produce strings in $L$ isn't enough: you have to prove that for all partitionings $wyz$ to prove the language nonregular.

In this case there exists a partitioning for $a^pb^p$ ($p$ being a pumping length of $L$) that produces strings in $L$: $w = \epsilon , y = a^p, z = b^p$. So we can't prove it as nonregular using the lemma - which is good because the language is indeed regular.